# Grails URL Mapping Precedence Rules

Tags: grails, url-routing

Take the following URL mapping with Grails

```
'/api/abcdef' (resources: 'abcDef')
'/api/abc' (resources: 'abc')
```

A call to `/api/abcdef` invokes the `AbcController.index()` with a `format` parameter of `def`, rather than `AbcDefController`. However the call `/api/abcdef/1` is resolved correctly to `AbcDefController.show()`. This looks like a bug as `grails url-mapping-report` would report

```
|   GET    | /api/abcdef                                      | Action: index    |
```

goes under `AbcDefController`.

However if change the order of the two URL's to

```
'/api/abc' (resources: 'abc')
'/api/abcdef' (resources: 'abcDef')
```

Grails would resolve `/api/abcdef` to `AbcDefController.index()` correctly.

But in either case `/api/abc123` would resolve to `AbcController.index()` with a `format` parameter of `123`

What is the mechanism for the precedence of URL mapping? Are the above behaviors right? I am with Groovy 2.4.5 and Grails 2.5.3.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? If so, I'd love if you could post it here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> [W]hen two mappings could apply to the same incoming URI, the one that
>   wins is the one that has:
>
> 1. Fewer double wildcards (** or $var**), or if both are equal then
> 2. Fewer single wildcards (* or $var), or if both are equal then
> 3. More non-wildcard path segments, or if both are equal then
> 4. The furthest left wildcard (/foo/*/baz beats /foo/bar/*), or if both have their leftmost wildcard in the same place then
> 5. The one with more constraints

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12214694/715608

Comment: I saw this post before. But still could not figure why `/api/abc123` would be mapped to `AbcController` and by what rule the order of `/api/abc` and `/api/abcdef` matters